# Can we implement a list on ActionBar using Sherlock Library in Android?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using Action Bar in my application to implement Tab Fragments. I am successful in it. But getting a small problem.  I am in a need of a drop-down list at the Right Corner of the action bar and a search button. Please see the image: 
[image]

You can see the red marked buttons that i need to show in Action bar and below the actionbar we have tab fragments. I am successful in generating the Fragments but getting problem in showing these buttons on Actionbar. Please help me

Comment: Check out the ActionbarSherlock github, it has an example app with all the things it can perfectly explained and shown.

Comment: That sample is very much complicated, and also in that sample they have not provide TabsFragment + ActoinBar implementation in one.

Comment: No it isn't... every possibility has it's own Activity showing it off. Can't be simpler... Just take some time to investigate instead of asking others.

Answer (score 1):

The overflow button is automatically generated but if you have a phone with hardware button it wont show up. You shouldn't try to force it to show up as it goes against ussual behaviour for people with phones that have a hardware button.